# Rake db:migrate error - paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have installed Paperclip but I have error when I try to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

after

```
rails generate paperclip asset photo
```

I get

> cannot load such file -- paperclip/tasks/attachments

What is wrong? This folder exists with that file.

Comment: Try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Comment: nothing , still cannot load such file -- paperclip/tasks/attachments

Comment: can you provide the content of the generated migration file?

Comment: class AddAttachmentPhotoToAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :assets do |t|
      t.attachment :photo
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :assets, :photo
  end
end

Comment: as you can see it did not generate migration like in http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip   - im very beginner :)

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. I am using mongoid and don't think migration is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: efectiva, so how did you install paperclip? Did you put it in your Gemfile and then ran "bundle install"?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried downloading it as a plugin (rails plugin install ... ), I saw the same problem. I deleted the plugins from vendor/plugins directory and then added the paperclip gem to gemfile (`gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"`) and everything now works. You may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure paperclip is loaded and the version which supports attachments, do

```
bundle show paperclip
```

Open the gem in text editor and check if paperclip/tasks/attachments.rb is present. If no, then the version of the gem needs to be upgraded or uninstall all paperclip gem versions and do a fresh install. paperclip-3.5.0 works.

If the version is correct and if it still throws error, include

```
require 'paperclip'
```

in your boot.rb.

This forces rails to include the gem at boot time.